# Recovering funds in ETH wrongly sent between exchanges to address without contract

Tags: ether, addresses, cpp-ethereum

I sent some funds in ETH from bitstamp to another exchange and missread the warnings on the receiving end telling me not to send from smart contract addresses, the transaction left and its confirmed but it hasnt made its way to the receiving address, how can I recover the funds?

Thanks for any help

Comment: keep us updated with this, i've done the same thing. i've opened a ticked and am waiting for an answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't recover the funds, once they're gone from your wallet you can't control them.

You may however be able to contact the second exchange and explain the issue. They may be able to find and credit your deposit.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do yourself, but you may be able to contact Bitstamp. They should have the private, and if you contact support they *might* recover the funds for you. I've heard that Bitstamp's support is pretty slow, so don't expect a response in the next week.